# We want to get user's job info of Azure Active Direcotry

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I am trying to get user info of Azure Active Directory with Teams channel.

I can get `TeamsChannelAccount` object with `TeamsInfo.get_memeber()` but user's job info of AAD is not in `TeamsChannelAccount` object.

How can I get the user's job info from Teams's turn_context with botframework sdk?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why sort of job info are you looking for? Can you link to a code reference that shows the actual data structure you're trying to retrieve?

Comment: This is because we want to limit the functions that can be used by referring to the user's job info in the service accessed from the bot.

Comment: [TeamsInfo.get_member](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/python/api/botbuilder-core/botbuilder.core.teams.teamsinfo?view=botbuilder-py-latest#get-member-turn-context--botbuilder-core-turn-context-turncontext--member-id--str-----botbuilder-schema-teams--models-py3-teamschannelaccount)

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your bot to retrieve AAD info in any channel, your bot will need to authenticate the user with OAuth. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication).

If you don't want to make the user sign in to AAD when they've already signed into Teams, you could alternatively have the bot use the info it gets from Teams to look up any additional job info in your company's database. I suspect you'll want to use the user's email address to do this, but you could potentially use the other properties available in the [`TeamsChannelAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/python/api/botbuilder-schema/botbuilder.schema.teams.teamschannelaccount) class. You would need to set up some kind of API for the bot to access the data if there isn't one already.

Depending on how flexible you are, a third solution may be to use [Teams single sign-on](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso). This is only available in Teams tabs and not Teams conversations, so rather than having an actual Teams bot you'd just have a [Web Chat bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/07.advanced-web-chat-apps/d.sso-for-teams) hosted on a page that gets accessed in a Teams tab. Note that this solution is very advanced, and Teams SSO is still in developer preview.

Comment: I tried using the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get the user info. I am trying to get specific user info using the userprincipalname contained in [`TeamsChannelAccout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/python/api/botbuilder-schema/botbuilder.schema.teams.teamschannelaccount?view=botbuilder-py-latest).

Comment: I registered the app and [Add permissions to access web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-permissions-to-access-web-apis)([User.Read.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-permissions-to-access-web-apis)). I got a token and ran the API, but it returned `'code':'Authorization_RequestDenied','message':'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.'`.

Comment: I made a mistake in setting permissions for Graph's API. I had set the type Delegated, but it was of type Application correctly. I was able to get the user information from the Graph.

Comment: @Taka - It sounds like you've resolved your issue now. Are you willing to upvote and accept this answer?